# Can't create an outlet with a bar button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I'm trying to have a user press `Done` and then an alert will be returned. So here's the issue. When I try to create an outlet from the `Done` button I can't. This is all I see

[image]

I'd expect for the little window to pop up then I'd be able to create it. Any ideas? I'm trying to add the outlet in my `ViewController.swift` file

[GitHub download](https://github.com/idrisk/Done/archive/master.zip)

Comment: Tap once to bar button and then try to create outlet/action

Comment: Yeah it's selected. I can't create it though @mstysf

Comment: Could be bug or something? Clean you project and restart Xcode. It may work

Comment: Cleaned and restarted already. Same issue. @mstysf

Comment: Are you sure the `ViewController.swift` is the right file? And try to add outlet to somewhere different place. For example above the `didRecieveMemoryWarning` method.

Comment: Just tried both of my files, `ViewController.swift` and `AppDelegate.swift`. Can't create it anywhere. @mstysf

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Do you want a UIAlert view to pop up on clicking "done" and then based on the action selected go somewhere?  BTW - if you post to github someone likely can debug it quickly.

Comment: Well I just want to create an action when "done" is clicked on essentially. The alert was just an example. So another example would be when it's clicked on, I'd return a message in the console @SteveRosenberg

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters on the solution.  I would post to git hub a stripped down version and let us look at it.   Make sure the right file is selected as the class in the identity inspector.

Comment: I just created a new project. And it still won't work. So I just added a link to the project on github @SteveRosenberg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to make sure your UIViewControler in the storyboard is set to the right class:
[image]

Comment: Magically it works. It was set to `UINavigationItem` earlier. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: That has happened to me more than once. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Per the solution recommended by everyone:

[image]